# How to implement search box to find any text inside any <div> using Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

[This is my search box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B01ZC.png)

and Here is the HTML code. In this block of code, I'm looping through an array of objects using ***ngFor**. So that `<div>` tags are generated dynamically.

```
`<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:15px !important; padding-right: 15px !important;">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header BlueTheme">Deal Comments Forms</div>
    <div class="card-header GreyTheme d-inline-flex" style="height:9%">
        <div class="searchControl inline-block-panel align-self-stretch form-inline" style="width: 56%">
            <p>Find Text:</p>
            <input type="search" name="searchTextBox" [(ngModel)]="searchText" style="border-radius: 5px;" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button (click)="onFirstSearchButtonClick()" class="btn btn-primary">First</button>
                <button (click)="onNextSearchButtonClick()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                <button (click)="onTakeMeFirstBlcokButtonClick()" class="btn btn-primary">Take me to first block</button>
                <button (click)="onTakeMePreviousBlcokButtonClick()" class="btn btn-primary">Take me to previous block</button>
                <button (click)="onTakeMeNextBlcokButtonClick()" class="btn btn-primary">Take me to next block</button>
                <button (click)="onTakeMeLastBlcokButtonClick()" class="btn btn-primary">Take me to last block</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap" style="margin-bottom: 20px; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);"
             *ngFor="let commentLibrary of commentLibraries">
            <!-- ********************** <Comment Type> **************************-->
            <div class="d-inline-flex child1">
                <p><strong><u>Comment Type:</u></strong></p>
                <p class="ml-3">{{ commentLibrary.CommentType.CommentTypeName }}</p>
            </div>
            <!-- ********************** </Comment Type> **************************-->
            <!-- ************************* <Comment> *****************************-->
            <div class="flex-column child2">
                <p class="header"><u>Comment:</u></p>
                <p style="border:ridge; padding-left:10px;">{{ commentLibrary.Comment }}</p>
            </div>
            <!-- ************************ </Comment> *****************************-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

**First Button Click: -**

- Now on click of First button how to search the text **inside the
  comment section** and **highlight** the found text and **move
  cursor** to found text as well.

**NextButton Click: -**

- On click of Next button search the text from the current cursor position and **highlight** the found text and **move cursor** to found text as well. **do not restart** at the beginning of the form

**Take me to the first block: -**

- Move the cursor to the first comment block.

**Take me to the previous block: -**

- Move the cursor to the previous comment block with respect to the current cursor position.

**Take me to the next block: -**

- Move the cursor to the next comment block with respect to the current cursor position.

**Take me to the last block: -**

- Move the cursor to the last comment block.

I tried this way, but It is not fulfilling my requirements and behaves abnormally(i.e It finds texts and `<tags>` as well and after clearing search box it clears my comments block as well.)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'highlight'
})

export class HighlightSearch implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: any, args: any): any {
    var re = new RegExp(args, 'gi'); //'gi' for case insensitive and can use 'g' if you want the search to be case sensitive.
    return value.replace(re, "<mark>" + args + "</mark>");
    }
}
```